# .eslintrc file not overriding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have this rule turned on: `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",`
but am attempting to override it

```
    "overrides": [
        {
         "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
          "excludedFiles": "**/*.js",
          "rules": {
            "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
          }
        }
      ],
```

essentially I want it to ignore all `.js` files but only to check `.ts` files. but when I run `yarn lint` it's showing errors just in `.js` files. any ideas?

Comment: Close & restart IDE?

Comment: @AseemGautam that'll do more than restarting eslint server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line inside rules:

```
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md) for more info on usage.